# Parse a JSON gives JsResultException

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying to parse a JSON which may or may not have a field. So I made the field option. But when I try to parse the JSON it results in `JsResultException`

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

import play.api.libs.json
import play.api.libs.json.Json


case class Test(field1: String , field2: Seq[String] = Seq.empty[String])

object Test{

  implicit val format = Json.format[Test]
}

val t = Test("1")

println(s"here = ${t.field2}")


val test  = """""{"field1":"test1"}"""""""

//Json.fromJson[Test](Json.parse(test), T)
Json.parse(test).as[Test]
```

Exception:

```
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((/field1,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/field2,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(test2.sc:19)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(test2.sc:19)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(test2.sc:69)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(test2.sc:9)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$class.as(test2.sc:17)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsString.as(test2.sc:42)
    at com.rallyhealth.healthvault.files.dao.A$A1$A$A1.get$$instance$$res0(test2.sc:21)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(test2.sc:54)
```

Tried this

```
import play.api.libs.json
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Test(field1: String = "", field2: Seq[String] = Seq.empty[String])

object Test {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    implicit val jsonFormat: json.Format[Test] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Test]


    val test = """""{"field1":"test1"}"""""""

    //Json.fromJson[Test](Json.parse(test), T)
    val value = Json.parse(test).as[Test]
    println(value)
  }
}
```

I am still getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.$anonfun$as$2(JsReadable.scala:25)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:56)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.as(JsReadable.scala:24)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.as$(JsReadable.scala:23)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsString.as(JsValue.scala:86)
    at kavya.Test$.main(GetOrElse.scala:18)
    at kavya.Test.main(GetOrElse.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the parameters must be of type `Option`, that it's working.

```
case class Test(field1: Option[String], field2: Option[Seq[String]])
```

The simplest solution is to set Default values if you don't want to change the signature:

```
case class Test(field1: String = "", field2: Seq[String] = Seq.empty[String])

implicit val jsonFormat: Format[Test] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Test]
```

Comment: I tried this. But still getting 

Exception in thread "main" play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))))
 at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.$anonfun$as$2(JsReadable.scala:25)
 at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:56)
 at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.as(JsReadable.scala:24)
 at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.as$(JsReadable.scala:23)
 at play.api.libs.json.JsString.as(JsValue.scala:86)

Comment: val test = """""{"field1":"test1"}"""""""

    val value = Json.parse(test).as[Test]
    println(value)

Comment: running that code works - I just had to adjust `val test = """{"field1":"test1"}"""` see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/rpC6uFX/0